# Dynamically change Telerik Grid formatting

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I have request where i need to change grid formatting on drop down action

where i have detailed option:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/clientrowtemplate?theme=forest

and default format should be like

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid?theme=forest

any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that an easy way would be having 2 grids and hiding the grid according to the selected option on the dropdown. If not, you will need to change the columns for the grid to use templates or not, which I think will be a pain

Comment: thnx, i was hoping for different solution :)

Comment: yeah, unfortunately for MVC is kind of difficult to change that on the fly since they are not server controls :S